# How to run linqpad 2.x and 4.x side by side?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, linqpad

I uses [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for running code snippets.

I need to run some code that targets 3.5 for which there is separate legacy build.

My question is how to run linqpad side by side?

Comment: I downloaded the legacy version, and I ran it just fine, while having the new version running.  What problem are you having?

Comment: I tried to run side by side and legacy linqpad is not running. By design it seems to be that linqpad extracts itself `%UserProfile%AppData\Local\LINQPad` and uses latest version. It also auto updates itself. Problem is I am not able to run code (that target in .NET 3.5) in LinqPad as newest version targets itself to .NET 4.5. I may be wrong about the linqpad design, but somehow it is running new version on launching legacy version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQPad 2.x and LINQPad 4.x are totally independent and happily run side-by-side. This is true whether you're using the the installed version or the standalone executable. Regarding updates, these are also independent: LINQPad 2.x stores updates in %programdata%\updates whereas LINQPad 4.x stores updates in %programdata%\updates40.

What exactly happens when you run LINQPad 2.x? What version does it say is running in Help | About?

I take it you have .NET Framework 3.5 installed on the machine?

Comment: You are right. It was my mistake. I was guessing from strikingly similar interface of both 2.x and 4.x version (nothing seemed different apart from version information). My related question is how to know **which runtime version linqpad targets** to execute code snippet and is it possible to change the target runtime?

Comment: LINQPad 2.x targets Framework 3.5; LINQPad 4.x targets Framework 4.0/4.5. You can probably force LINQPad 2.x to run on Framework 4.x, but you won't get proper access to all the features of the Framework.

Comment: @JoeAlbahari I have both 4.5 and 4. how can I force it to use 4 ?

Comment: You can't: if 4.5 is available, LINQPad will let you use its additional features.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble running both versions side by side try downloading the portable versions of the application.

**Edit**
It appears there is no portable version of LINQPad 2 available for download.
You can try installing the v2 and then download a portable version of v4.