# LINQPad 5 switch between compilers

Tags: c#, linqpad

Is there a way to switch back and forth between the Roslyn compiler and the CSharpCodeProvider using LINQPad 5. I'm investigating an issue that I think works differently in both compilers (the type name of a lambda function) and would like an easy way of switching between compilers

Comment: As it says on [LINQPad's site](http://www.linqpad.net/howlinqpadworks.aspx), *LINQPad 5 compiles your queries using the Microsoft Roslyn libraries (in the past it used .NET's CSharpCodeProvider and VBCodeProvider).* I would suggest that means that, no, there isn't. You could just download an older version and run them [side-by-side](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14320795/215552). They also have a [uservoice site](https://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions) where you could ask for the feature.